What should I put between steel beam and concrete block wall to fill void and ensure constant pressure?
Long story short my house needed some foundation bracing. I got a structural engineer out here to give me the plans. Here is verbatim what was in the report for the area I'm working on:

Steel soldier beams can be installed across the
affected area placed every 4ft on center. The soldier beams shall be positively anchored
to the floor joists and the concrete floor (or be installed with new footings). Non-shrink
grout shall be installed between the soldier beam and wall for consistent bearing between
the soldier beam and concrete block wall.

Here are some pictures of what I have done:
https://i.postimg.cc/h4wVvwp5/IMG-2381.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/XvVCt0Yp/IMG-2375.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/g0NZWBx4/IMG-2376.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/1tXN5c6S/IMG-2378.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/ZRQv9BFd/IMG-2379.jpg
As you can see the gap at the bottom is 2 inches or sometimes slightly above as the top is set mostly flush against the wall.
Now my question is, what should I use to fill the gaps between the wall and beams? The space is 4 inches wide, about 2 inches thick and gets thinner towards the top, and somewhere around 6-7 feet tall.
I got some precision grout which I understand is also known as structural grout from Home Depot but the consistency was extremely thin even when I mixed 1.5 bags with the same level of water for plastic consistency for just 1 bag. I did get a few quotes from companies and here's an example of finished work that they had done one someone else's house:
https://i.postimg.cc/SsYCffKr/11-1.jpg
https://i.postimg.cc/5ywzZ9LQ/11-2.jpg
Additionally I have found a post about someone accomplishing this with "stiff concrete" and outlining the process here, but I am unsure of what stiff concrete is.
https://pro.homeadvisor.com/article.show.Stabilizing-Basement-Walls-with-Steel-I-Beams.13691.html

Non-shrink grout shall be installed between the soldier beam and wall for consistent bearing between the soldier beam and concrete block wall.  This is what the engineer wants, so this is what you use.  Using anything else will need the engineer's okay/sign off to stay in permitted work and to keep your insurance happy/paying any future claims.

Thanks, I guess my question is more of how should I apply this non shrink grout. I cannot put forms around most of the beams because of their positioning so is there anything that is a firm enough consistency to stack it vertically?

Should ask the structural engineer that did the report.  I have a feeling the grout was supposed to be done first before placing the beams, so it could set.

@crip659 IDK how you'd grout up the wall first and end up with a flat enough surface to mate with the beam though.

@Slater in your last link it looks like the guy is applying the grout without forms.  Presumably the slump of the mix is stuff enough to not need forms, or he's simply building up in lifts so the bottom doesn't blow out.

Have you tried mixing up a bit of the grout with much less water? I had to do some similar work without forms in a wall and found the bag instructions even for plastic consistency were still too much water for moldable freestanding grout.
